# Selenium WebDriver Python - can't capture the error message that shows up

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to track down a popup(?) error here after typing an invalid email and display the text in the console but can't find it anywhere.

I could not find this error an message in the source code.
I tried using iframe and switch_to_alert but it didn't give any results (nothing found in both cases)

My goal is to intercept and output to the console this message:

> A part following '@' should not contain the symbol '_'.

How to locate this element on the page?And if it is not possible, how to intercept this error?

Link to that form is here: https://www.uke.gov.pl/formularz-kontaktowy/

I tried to catch that error by switch to frame/alert but didn't find that

also tried with: `error_messages = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.error")` and found but no that message there.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, we can create XPath expressions only for elements in the HTML structure. When a tooltip acts as a validation message because of the `type="email"` attribute, it's tricky to directly inspect or make an XPath for it. However, if you want to check the validation message, you can easily get the message content using the `get_attribute()` method.

Here's the code I used to tackle this task.

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.uke.gov.pl/formularz-kontaktowy/")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/span[1]/a").click()
dropdown_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//select[@id='temat']")
dropdown = Select(dropdown_element)
dropdown.select_by_visible_text("Sekretariat Prezesa")
email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='email']")
email.send_keys("Michaeljames@_gmail.com")
email.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(5)
message = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='email']").get_attribute("validationMessage")
print(message)
```

You can additionally verify the presence of the validation message by executing `$0.validationMessage` in the [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk3aN.png).